# Why is tex formatting not working?

Tags: discussion

Why is tex formatting not working in this site? Is it because mathematical notations are not much important for this site? May be tex formatting might not be useful for other purposes (not sure about that). But I see people copying unicode characters in answers to work around this. Here is an [example](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/47248/31680). **I just wanted to clarify if that is the reason**. (There may be other reasons like allowing tex formatting requires more work on the site which outweighs the advantage of allowing them)

Comment: I would like to see mathjax here as well or whatever they are currently using at the math SE.

Comment: Making a 6 year old 'status declined' posts isn't very useful... If you want MathJax, make a new 'feature-request' meta post. If you don't, I might. There are many questions on philosophy of mathematics that can very much use mathjax .